# Git auth to bitbucket fails after migrating to Jira

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

I had an account on bitbucket and I signed up to Jira. I accepted the EULA and now I log on to Bitbucket with my Jira account which is a combination of my email address and a newly specified password. 
I can log on fine with these on the website but I am having difficulty with the git clone command I invoked by pressing the CLONE button on GUI. The command includes my `username@bitbucket` instead of `my@email.address` e.g.

```
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/user2/maoist.git 
Cloning into 'maoist'... 
Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org':
```

Now that username is not valid anymore since I signed up to Jira. Tried editing the command and changing `username@bitbucket.org` to `my@email.address`, but that didn't work. So how do I clone maoist then?

Answer (score 2):

I just added my ssh public key to bitbucket under Settings/Security/SSH keys and the problem is solved.